# Shopify API integration problem. (Need to get all invoice through the Shopify API)

Tags: shopify-api

Hello Shopify API experts.
This time, I am working on Shopify API integration to my website.
There is a 170k invoice in the Shopify store. I want to get all invoices through the API.
But I am getting 7k only after googling the search.

https://{{api_key}}:{{api_password}}@{{store_name}}.myshopify.com/admin/api/{{api_version}}/orders/count.json
Am I wrong?
*I think orders and invoices are different?

Any help will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

> [GET%20/admin/api/2021-07/orders.json?status=any](http://GET%20/admin/api/2021-07/orders.json?status=any)

There are 3 statuses in Shopify order.

> open, closed, cancelled.

Explain for Status filed in Shopify API GET request.

> Filter orders by their status.
> (default: open)
> open: Show only open orders.
> closed: Show only closed orders.
> cancelled: Show only canceled orders.
> any: Show orders of any status, including archived orders.

To get all order lists, I had to add "Status=any" for GET request link.

Reference link:
https://shopify.dev/api/admin/rest/reference/orders/order#index-2021-07